# Where to get a list of Kingfisher's cancelled flights?

Tags: kingfisher-airlines

Where can I get info on Kingfisher Airlines's flight cancellations? I tried on their site but no luck finding any lists regarding that.

I can put this as a new question if needed but will ask here right now - does a traveler have any rights if a flight is cancelled by a company such as Kingfisher Airlines, which is in a bit of a pickle right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this [news report](http://www.ndtv.com/article/india/kingfisher-files-fresh-flight-schedule-with-dgca-178729?slider), Kingfisher has filed a fresh flight schedule with DGCA (Director General of Civil Aviation). Apparently, they have cut down their total number of flights to 170 (from around 248) daily.

Here is the link for updated flight schedules for the month of February.

http://www.flykingfisher.com/pdf/Flight_schedule_23February2012.pdf.

To answer the second part of your question,

> "We have received reports about large-scale cancellations. They are
>   bound to inform us when they cut their schedule. But they have not
>   done so," DGCA chief E K Bharat Bhushan said the DGCA had sent messages to all other airlines to accommodate
>   passengers stranded due to the Kingfisher cancellations. "They have to
>   do this without enhancing the fares," he said.

[Link to report](http://www.ndtv.com/article/india/kingfisher-cancels-30-flights-vijay-mallya-apologises-to-passengers-178106).

According to DGCA regulation (Section 3.3 [Civil Aviation Requirements](http://dgca.nic.in/rules/car-ind.htm)), when an airline cancels its flight due to reason within its control, it needs to compensate the passenger, provide alternative flight or mode of other transport.

The amount of compensation could vary from Rs 2,000-4,000. In such a situation, an airline can put its passenger on the flight of other airline by paying them the price. If the other airline has vacant seats, it cannot refuse to take passenger.

I am not sure how easy it will be to get a seat in another airlines though. Another factor to consider is that some of the routes that Kingfisher was operating in was serviced exclusively by them.

Comment: Great find, thanks. I presume a schedule for March isn't available yet? What does that quote from the report mean? If my flight is cancelled, I get to go on a flight by another airlines with no additional cost (provided that there are seats available)?

Comment: Also, if no other flights are available, does Kingfisher compensate for that in some way such as providing meals and accommodation?

Comment: Yes, you have to be provided amenities while you are waiting for your alternate flight. And all these are applicable only if you have provided the airlines with means to contact you and they have not informed you of cancellation at least 3 hours in advance.